# Hiding the product from the client in the factory pattern

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I have a factory class `CipherBuilder` with a static method `build` that returns a `StringCipher` object to the client.
I want to hide the `StringCipher` class, so the client can only get an object of this type through the `CipherBuilder` factory, and can't call the class constructor directly (but it should still be able to use its public methods).

My current implementation is to create another package separate from the client code, and put in it the three classes, `CipherBuilder` factory (which is public), the `StringCipher` (package private) and a public interface to it (`IStringCipher`). This way the client can't call the constructor directly, but it can still use the public methods through the interface.

But since I had to create a new package just to hide a class, this feels like a hack. Is there a better way to do this (in Java), while keeping StringCipher in the same package as the client code, and keeping `StringCipher` and `CipherBuilder` in separate files?

Comment: Let the CipherBuilder create a IStringCipher. And StringCipher be hidden somehow. It could indeed mean a package private class & constructor. A sub-package is customary too. One could make the class a static inner class of the factory class too.

Comment: So there's no way to do this while keeping StringCipher in the same package as the client code? Can I do the static inner class in a separate file?

Comment: Another approach: **Java SPI, Service Provider Interface**. That is a mechanism by which for instance the XML parser(s) are discovered and loaded. As to the original question: I am not entirely certain how "nice" you want to specify things. (By the way at least one `package` is the norm.) Having a class with a private constructor (like the factory maybe), you could pass the factory to the constructor and check for a non-null object. Ugly! (Better wait for java 9 with modules.) Sorry for the chaos.

Answer (score 2):

To keep `CipherBuilder` and `StringCipher` in the same package, you could make the constructor of `StringCipher` protected, that way the client can't construct `StringCipher` but the `CipherBuilder` still has access since both classes are in the same package.

I hope this helps

Comment: The point was to hide the class without creating a separate package for it. I'll edit the post to explain this.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a better solution. Can you include the "If the client classes are in the same package" sentence in the answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

there are few things how you could achieve it.

you could defined your `StringCipher` class as private class inside `CipherBuilder` class. If `StringCipher` will be coded to interface, then factory method in `CipherBuilder` could return you an interface;

other solution, if you don't want interface, will be defining `CipherBuilder` and `StringCipher` in same package, and set access level for `StringCipher`'s constructor as package (no  access level modifier). Then `StringCipher` could be created only inside package.

Comment: The second solution is what I'm currently doing. Can the first solution be done while keeping the StringCipher in a separate file from CipherBuilder?

Comment: @devil0150 maybe i misunderstand you, but second solution wont work if both classes will be in separate packages, and in your problem description you suggesting you have separate packages. and first solution wont work if you have private constructor. unless you use reflection, but that will be bad practice for this case

Comment: @devil0150 and of course you could separate them, and change access level, but again, that will be same as second solution

Comment: I have separate packages. One package for the client code, and one for the other three classes, StringCipher, IStringCipher, CipherBuilder (I'll make this more clear in the question). What I want to do is merge these two packages while still hiding the StringCipher constructor.

Comment: @devil0150 i recommend you to don't merge packages if it is not necessary. But if you want to do this, and you want to prevent accessing `StringCipher` constructor then only way to do this, is to define your class inside factory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is:

1) Create your package

2) Inside you package create:

```
   public class CipherBuilder{...}
   public class IStringCipher{...}
   class StringCipher {...}
```

No one outside your package will see CipherBuilder.

Comment: I'm assuming the third line should be StringCipher. But still, that is what I am currently doing.

Comment: Yes, just changed it. I see, you need the Client in the same package. Maybe you can define an asbtract StringCipher class in a separate file and a Inner class into CipherBuilder that implements it. Does it even make sense?